# Format and pretty print log via tail

Tags: json, logging, grep, jq, tail

I have this log file that I check on a frequent basis and because of the format of it, it's quite easier to read when pretty printed. I'd like to do so in a tail.

Logs in the file like:

```
2019-07-04T09:53:04-07:00   some.package.placeholder.stderr {"log": "The content", "foo": "bar", "baz": "blah"}
2019-07-04T10:15:37-07:00   some.package.placeholder.stderr {"log": "I'm actually", "foo": "bar", "baz": "blah"}
2019-07-04T10:15:37-07:00   some.package.placeholder.stderr {"log": "Interested on", "foo": "bar", "baz": "blah"}
```

And I want to do something similar to

```
tail -f myLogFile | grep [...?...] | jq '.log'
```

So when tailing I get:

```
The content
I'm actually
Interested on
```

Or even:

```
2019-07-04T09:53:04-07:00   The content
2019-07-04T10:15:37-07:00   I'm actually
2019-07-04T10:15:37-07:00   Interested on
```

Comment: Can `some.package.placeholder.stder` contain spaces?

Comment: @Cyrus not for this case, but the timestamp, the `package.placeholder` and the actual json can be separated by tabs/spaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU grep for `-o`:

```
$ tail file | grep -o '{[^}]*}' | jq -r '.log'
The content
I'm actually
Interested on
```

With any awk:

```
$ tail file | awk 'sub(/.*{/,"{")' | jq -r '.log'
The content
I'm actually
Interested on

$ tail file | awk '{d=$1} sub(/.*{/,""){$0="{\"date\": \""d"\", " $0} 1' | jq -r '.date + " " + .log'
2019-07-04T09:53:04-07:00 The content
2019-07-04T10:15:37-07:00 I'm actually
2019-07-04T10:15:37-07:00 Interested on
```

That last one works by merging the date field from the input into the json so then jq can just select and print it with the log field.

Comment: Presumably one would also want to use the —unbuffered command-line option of jq?

Comment: @peak idk to be honest, I'm just learning `jq` but it does seem likely you'd want to use something to turn off buffering so if thats what that option is for `jq` then yes and you might also want to add a `fflush()` to the awk commands after each line is printed or insert a `stdbuf` or similar call.

Answer (score 2):

If the log lines are tab delimited, you can read the lines in raw and split on tabs. Which you could then parse the json and filter to your hearts content, and recombine as necessary.

```
$ tail -f myLogFile | jq -Rr 'split("\t") | [.[0], (.[2] | fromjson.log)] | join("\t")'
2019-07-04T09:53:04-07:00   The content
2019-07-04T10:15:37-07:00   I'm actually
2019-07-04T10:15:37-07:00   Interested on
```

Comment: That looked awesome but when I tried it with `jq` version 1.6 on cygwin I just got `assertion "cb == jq_util_input_next_input_cb" failed: file "/usr/src/ports/jq/jq-1.6-1.x86_64/src/jq-1.6/src/util.c", line 371, function: jq_util_input_get_position
Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: Hmmm I'm not in the position to be able to debug and see what's causing this, but judging by the message, I guess it's an issue with how tail passes along the output. I tried it myself at the time in git bash and it doesn't work in real-time which I assume it's supposed to do.

Comment: I get the same error message from just `jq '...' file` as I do from `tail file | jq`. It may be just a cygwin thing, idk. I'm just starting to learn `jq` so haven't used it much. A quick google came up with https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1588 but idk if it's the same issue or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thing I use that can be used in a pipe and with file args:

```
cat /usr/local/bin/j2t
#!/bin/bash

function usage {
  cat <<EOF
Usage:
        $0 <json filename>
    or
        tail -F <json filename> | $0
EOF
}

if (($# == 0)); then
    {
        sed "s/@\(timestamp\)/\1/" | jq -r '[.timestamp, .pri.facility, .pri.severity, .message] | join("\t")'
    } < /dev/stdin

else
    if [ -r "$1" ] ; then
        sed "s/@\(timestamp\)/\1/" $1 | jq -r '[.timestamp, .pri.facility, .pri.severity, .message] | join("\t")'
    else
        help
    fi
fi
```

eg: (if your daemon.log is json)

```
j2t /var/log/daemon.log
level: 63, builder: awillia2)
2021-08-14T00:00:06.820642+00:00        daemon  INFO     Starting Run Clamscan...
2021-08-14T00:00:06.846405+00:00        daemon  INFO     Started Run Clamscan.
```

Should probably reformat the time, it's a bit long.